# How did Odin Quincannon's actions serve God?

Tags: character, preacher

In the TV show [Preacher](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5016504/), Jesse Custer ordered Odin Quincannon to "Serve God". And it looks like he will, but then in a meeting with green agriculture representatives, he killed them all with a shotgun except for the mayor. And then he wants to demolish Jesse's church. And he is justified that he was serving the God of meat. But what is the God of meat? And how did his action serve the god of meat? He even made a daughter out of meat before dying from the explosion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The point was that the things that Jesse was using his ability for had unintended consequences and he was being careless with them and not thinking about their implications. We can compare this to the traditional story of the [monkey's paw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey%27s_Paw) where the individual is allowed three wishes and wishes that his wife were alive again but instead of getting his wife back, her corpse becomes reanimated like a zombie. It is also where we get common figures of speech like "be careful what you wish for".

### **What is the God of Meat?**

In this case, Jesse tells Odin to "serve god" but he doesn't specify *which* god. We all serve some sort of "god". If you want to get religious about it, you could talk about the many forms of idolatry. It is a pretty common theme in modern storytelling that humans have replaced traditional worship of deity with the worship of machines and technology and capitalism (see [American Gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Gods) by Neil Gaiman for a good example of this in literature). In Odin's case, his "god" was represented through his slaughter business.

### **How did Odin's actions serve the God of Meat?**

He served his god by killing those who were a threat to it. The green agriculture executives are naturally opposed to his business of killing animals for meat. So he eliminated them.